# logical expression not working when used as a case value in a switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to build a simple box movements controlling project.

I'm trying to use a **switch statement** as an alternative to lines of **if statements**.

In my code, I added the keydown event listener, so as to affect the CSS sytles when the user presses a key on their keyboard. This is my code:

```js
/** @format */

let box = document.getElementById("box");
document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyPress);
let verticalPosition = 0;
let horizontalPosition = 0;
let rotation = 0;
let key;
let stopHorizontalMovement;
let stopVerticalMovement;

function handleKeyPress(keyPressed) {
    key = keyPressed.code;

    switch (true) {
        /* For Vertical movement */
        case key === "ArrowDown": {
            verticalPosition = verticalPosition + 1;
            if (verticalPosition > 100) {
                verticalPosition = 100;
                /* Stop moving the box down when the edge meets the end of the viewport height */
            }
            break;
        }

        case key === "ArrowUp": {
            verticalPosition = verticalPosition - 1;
            if (verticalPosition < 0) {
                verticalPosition = 0;
                /* Stop moving the box down when the edge meets the start of the viewport height */
            }

            break;
        }

        /* For Horizontal movement */
        case key === "ArrowLeft": {
            horizontalPosition = horizontalPosition - 1;
            if (horizontalPosition < -40) {
                horizontalPosition = -40;
                /* Stop moving the box down when the edge meets the start of the viewport width */
            }
            break;
        }

        case key === "ArrowRight": {
            horizontalPosition = horizontalPosition + 1;
            if (horizontalPosition > 40) {
                horizontalPosition = 40;
                /* Stop moving the box down when the edge meets the end of the viewport width */
            }
            break;
        }

        /* For rotation of the box */

        case keyPressed.ctrlKey === true &&
            (key === "ArrowUp" || key === "ArrowRight"): {
            console.log("rotating");
            rotation = rotation + 30;
            break;
        }

        default:
        // break;
    }
  refresh();
}
function refresh() {
    box.style.top = verticalPosition + "vh";
    box.style.left = horizontalPosition + "vw";
    box.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
}
```

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* align-items: center; */
    background-color: rgb(6, 6, 65);
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

#box {
    background-color: red;
    width: 20%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

The code block that begins with the comment `/* For rotation of the box */` was to rotate the box clockwise when the `ctrl`, `ArrowUp`, or `ArrowRight` keys are pressed simultaneously. But it doesn't seem to work.

But when it was in the `if statement`, it does work:

```js
if (
        keyPressed.ctrlKey === true &&
        (key === "ArrowUp" || key === "ArrowRight")
    ) {
        rotation = rotation + 30;
      }
```

I really want to do this with the **switch statement**. I'd appreciate if anyone can help out.

Comment: "*I'm trying to use a switch statement as an alternative to lines of if statements.*" - why? Just don't do that, `switch(true)` only makes the code less readable.

Comment: I saw somewhere that it's better.

Comment: No. It's worse, and also - as you can see - it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh. So there's no fix to the switch statement's issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like previously you had multiple independent `if` statements. The `switch` statement (with a `break` on each case) however behaves more like an `else-if` chain, executing only the block on the *first* matching condition. So you'd never have the code that does movement and the code that does the rotation run both.

Put the rotation handling in a separate statement below the `switch` statement, which also means that you can use `switch` as intended, switching on the variable key and not on `true`:

```
function handleKeyPress(keyPressed) {
    switch (keyPressed.code) {
        /* For Vertical movement */
        case "ArrowDown": {
            verticalPosition = Math.min(100, verticalPosition + 1);
            break;
        }

        case "ArrowUp": {
            verticalPosition = Math.max(0, verticalPosition - 1);
            break;
        }

        /* For Horizontal movement */
        case "ArrowLeft": {
            horizontalPosition = Math.max(-40, horizontalPosition - 1);
            break;
        }

        case "ArrowRight": {
            horizontalPosition = Math.min(40, horizontalPosition + 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    /* For *additional* rotation of the box */
    if (keyPressed.ctrlKey === true &&
        (keyPressed.code === "ArrowUp" || keyPressed.code === "ArrowRight")
    ) {
        console.log("rotating");
        rotation = rotation + 30;
    }

    refresh();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had multiple independent **if statements**, but wanted to switch to using the switch statement. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, you can use `switch` only for exclusive conditional blocks that depend on the same variable

Comment: Alright. I understand now